# Why use asp:HyperLink

Tags: .net, asp.net, html

In what circumstances is it recommended to use the asp:HyperLink control?

I've come from a HTML background and am creating sites with ASP.NET and I tend to use raw HTML by default, whereas my colleagues use the asp: control versions.

In some cases that makes sense for the extra intellisense e.g. when creating `<label>`, but for asp:Hyperlink, it seems more straightforward to enter the anchor tag directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key benefit is that the Hyperlink is a control that can be programatically manipulated in the code-behind.

ASPX

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlLink" runat="server" />
```

ASPX.CS

```
hlLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/SomeFolder/SomePage.aspx?SomeKey={0}", someKey);
```

Comment: What does asp.Net MVC have to do with this?

Comment: Just the issue that in my experience, MVC is fast becoming the de-facto standard for new ASP.NET project work. So keeping your HTML skills is a must.

Comment: +1 James, good answer - although like Oskar I think the section about MVC adds unnecessary complexity to the answer and isn't particularly pertinent to the question!

Comment: Okay, I agree. I've removed the bit about MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the hyperlink, a lot of other controls suport the runat=server tag which allows the control to be used from code behind.  Makes life a lot simpler.

For example depending on an action that the user does, you can disable the hyperlink or change the navigateurl.

On the other hand, if you just want a static link, it is ok just to use an anchor tag